# The probability that a relation is symmetric, reflexive and both

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I have no idea where to start here. Isn't the number of relations on a given set infinite? Wouldn't that make everything 0 by the probability formula?

I know the definitions of reflexive and symmetric to be...

Reflexive <-> for all x in A, (x,x)
Symmetric <-> for all x in A, if x R y then y R x

> A. Given a set A, what is the probability that a relation R: A → A is
>   reflexive?
>
> B. Given a set A, what is the probability that a relation R: A → A is
>   symmetric?
>
> C. Given a set A, what is the probability that a relation R: A → A is
>   reflexive and symmetric?

Sorry I don't have more work to show but I have no idea how to go about this.

Edit: This is the entire question. No further information has been given.

Comment: is the set A finite or infinite? (and if infinite is it countable/uncountable)?

Comment: I guess it's a finite set. In an infinite set, these probabilities would be 0 unless I'm mistaken

Comment: The number of relations is a power of two, rather...

Comment: Yes, it's $2^{|A|^2}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp do you mean the question needs more information? This was all that was included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is the set, and $R$ a relation on that set, then $R\subseteq A{\times}A$; so the count of distinct relations on $A$ is $2^{{\lvert A\rvert}^2}$.

To proceed you have to have some model of the probability distribution of relations, and identify whether $A$ is finite or transfinite (countable, uncountable...).

Let us assume the set is finite, and the relations are selected unbiasedly.

Now a relation is reflexive if all the "diagonal" elements of $A{\times}A$ are in the relation.    There are $\lvert A\rvert$ such elements, and thus $2^{{\lvert A\rvert}}$ ways these may be selected for inclusion in a relation, of which selecting all is only one way.   So, under our assumption, the probability that a random relation is reflexive would be: $2^{-\lvert A\rvert}$.

Proceed likewise for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Assuming A is finite you can use combinatorics and set theory to solve this problem.

First, note that the cardinal value (amount for finite sets) of relations is $P(A ×A)$, which equals $2^{|A×A|}$.

Second, you want to count all the relation sets that are symmetric and reflexive and divide by the cardinal value you got from the first part, this is the trickier part. For example - for the reflexive, for all $x \in A$ , 
must be that  $<x,x>\in E$ (assuming $E$ is a relation above $A×A$). Now, how many sets can you make with this assumption? try solving with combinatorics.

Can you take it from here?